# Does an injective $\mathbb F_9$ vector space homomorphism $\mathbb F_9^5 \to \mathbb F_9^3$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, group-homomorphism

Does an injective $\mathbb F_9$  vector space homomorphism $\mathbb F_9^5 \to \mathbb F_9^3$ exist?

Is it able to solve that task by some technique?
If so, how is it working then?

Comment: What's $\mathbb{R}_9^5$? Also, you can only have homomorphisms between vector spaces with the same underlying field.

Comment: @jublikon: Sanity check: can you solve the problem for $\mathbb{R}$ in place of $\mathbb{F}_9$?

Comment: @Hurkyl: I think it should be possible for $(a,b,0,0,0) \in \mathbb R^5 \to (a,0,0) \in \mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @jublikon: addressing your comment + MooS's answer below, note that both $(1, 1, 0, 0, 0)$ and $(1, 2, 0, 0, 0)$ map to $(1, 0, 0)$, but clearly $(1, 1, 0, 0, 0) \neq (1, 2, 0, 0, 0)$. So your map is not injective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. There isn't even an injective map (of sets) because the sets are finite and the domain has more elements than the codomain.

Comment: So it would be possible with $\mathbb F_9^3 \to \mathbb F_9^5$?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I would really appreciate an example of $\mathbb F_9^3\to \mathbb F_9^5$ vector space homomorphism and how to make it out

Comment: Ask a separate question.