# Does an injective $\mathbb F_9$ vector space homomorphism $\mathbb F_9^3 \to \mathbb F_9^5$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, group-homomorphism

Does an injective $\mathbb F_9$  vector space homomorphism $\mathbb F_9^3 \to \mathbb F_9^5$ exist?

Is it able to solve that task by some technique?
If so, how is it working then?

I have posted a similiar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291597/does-an-injective-mathbb-f-9-vector-space-homomorphism-mathbb-f-95-to-ma#2291597) but with a mapping that is not a homomorphism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For example, consider the map which sends $(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{F}_9^3$ to $(a,b,c,0,0)\in \mathbb{F}_9^5$.

Comment: One thing to like about this answer is that it makes clear, in a subtle way, that the question doen not really depend on the choice of ground field and would have the same answer when $\mathbb{F}_9$ is replaced by any other $\mathbb{F}_q$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field. If $\phi: \mathbb{F}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^n$, and if $m \leq n$, then $\phi$ can be defined explicitly as an embedding, which is injective. (Simply annex $n - m$ zeros as components in your starting vector.) See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Field_theory) for more details.