# Does a surjective $\mathbb Q$ vector space homomorphism $\mathbb Q ^{5 \times 1} \to \mathbb Q^{3 \times 1}$ with rank $1$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Does a surjective $\mathbb Q$ vector space homomorphism $\mathbb Q ^{5 \times 1} \to \mathbb Q^{3 \times 1}$ with rank $1$ exist?

To solve that task I have written down the two definitions:

$\phi$ is surjective if $(\phi(s_1), ..., \phi(s_n))$ is a generating system of the codomain.

rank: $r_k\phi = dim_K(Im \phi)$ where $K$ is a field.

I think that the answer should be no, because I cannot find an image for $\phi$ where the rank is $1$. 
Because of $\mathbb Q^{3 \times 1}$ it should be $3$ like: $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$.

**Question**: Is that a correct guess? And what if the question would be: Does there exist a surjective $\mathbb Q$ vector space homomorphism $\mathbb Q ^{5 \times 1} \to \mathbb Q^{3 \times 1}$

**Note**: That question is related to the posts [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291617/does-an-injective-mathbb-f-9-vector-space-homomorphism-mathbb-f-93-to-ma) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2291597/does-an-injective-mathbb-f-9-vector-space-homomorphism-mathbb-f-95-to-ma).

**Edit**: According to @Travis comment a sample that needs some clarification for that task:

let

$\phi: \mathbb Q^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb Q^{1 \times 3} , 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d  \\
\end{pmatrix}  
\mapsto (2a-2b+c+5d \qquad-a+b+3c+d \qquad a-b-c+d) $

There is

$rk_{\mathbb Q}\phi = 2$ because $\{(7 \quad 0 \quad 2),(3 \quad 2 \quad 0)\}$ is a basis of $Im_{\phi}$ and thus $rk_{\phi}=dim(Im_{\phi})=2$

I understand why in that case the rank equals $2$. 
But that seems like a contradiction to the comment. 
I do not understand the difference here. What exactly is it?

Comment: If surjective, the rank should be the dimension of the image space.

Comment: You're correct: Any surjective linear map $V \to \Bbb Q^{3 \times 1}$ has rank $\dim \Bbb Q^{3 \times 1} = 3$.

Comment: @Travis I have edited my post

Comment: What is the contradiction that you see? If $\phi$ really has rank $2$ as claimed (I didn't check this myself), then $\phi$ cannot be a surjective. For example, if your claim about the basis is correct, then, e.g., $\pmatrix{-4&6&14}$ is not in the image of $\phi$.

Comment: I have misunderstood something. Now it is clear to me. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very concise answer: $\phi$ is surjective means that $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)$ is equal to the codomain, which for $\phi:\Bbb Q^{5 \times 1} \to \Bbb Q^{3 \times 1}$ means that $\operatorname{Im}(\phi) = \Bbb Q^{3 \times 1}$.  So, if $\phi$ is surjective, then 
$$
\operatorname{rank}(\phi) = \dim_{\Bbb Q}(\operatorname{Im}(\phi)) = \dim_{\Bbb Q}(\Bbb Q^{3 \times 1}) = 3
$$
So, $\phi$ cannot have a rank of $1$.

---

To show that there exists a surjective vector space homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Q^{5 \times 1} \to \Bbb Q^{3 \times 1}$, it suffices to provide an example.  One example is
$$
\phi(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5) = (x_1,x_2,x_3)
$$